# Plotly express contour

Tags: python, plotly, contour

Consider the following example of a heatmap plot taken from [the documentation](https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# Create the index for the data frame
x = np.linspace(-1,1, 6)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,6)
n_channel = [1, 2, 3, 4]

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

all_arrays = np.empty((0, 6, 6))

for n in n_channel:
    z = np.random.randn(len(y), len(x))
    all_arrays = np.vstack((all_arrays, [z]))

fig = px.imshow(
    all_arrays,
    facet_col=0,
)

for k in range(4):
    fig.layout.annotations[k].update(text='n_channel:{}'.format(k))
    
fig.show()
```

which produces the following plot

[image]

I would like to have a [contour plot](https://plotly.com/python/contour-plots/) instead which shares the axes and the color bar. Given the similarity between the two types of plots I was expecting that this could be achieved by simply replacing `imshow` by `contour`. It is not the case however.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The [plotly contour plot](https://plotly.com/python/contour-plots/) needs `plotly.graph_objects`, so just replace `imshow` by `contour` will not work.

Here is the code and I wrote some necessary comments:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create the index for the data frame
x = np.linspace(-1,1, 6)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,6)
n_channel = [1, 2, 3, 4]

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

all_arrays = np.empty((0, 6, 6))

for n in n_channel:
    z = np.random.randn(len(y), len(x))
    all_arrays = np.vstack((all_arrays, [z]))
    
# Initialize a subplot graph and the subtitles
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=4, subplot_titles=(tuple(map(str, range(4)))), shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True)

# Find min and max values for the color bar
min_value = np.min(all_arrays)
max_value = np.max(all_arrays)

# This part is plotting the graph and making sure the subplots share a same color bar 
for k in range(4):
    if k == 0:
        fig.add_trace(go.Contour(z=all_arrays[k, :, :], zmin=min_value, zmax=max_value), 1, k+1)
    else:
        fig.add_trace(go.Contour(z=all_arrays[k, :, :], showscale=False, zmin=min_value, zmax=max_value), 1, k+1)
        
# Update subplot titles
for k in range(4):
    fig.layout.annotations[k].update(text='n_channel:{}'.format(k))
    
fig.show()
```

Then you get the figure:
[image]